# Is any of the free law programs in Germany arranged or attendable online?

Tags: european-union, germany, online, legal-education, state-university

This question arose out of the answer given by Volker Siegel to [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67544/what-is-the-average-cost-of-attending-law-school).

Is it possible to establish admission online to without personal attendance or attend online after regular admission?

What, if any, program is closest to a fully online law program out of the free ones for EU and non-EU citizens?

This question is interesting because, for example in many states of the U.S., one who holds an LL or M. degree is permitted to attempt to absolve the admission prerequisite (for the U.S. typically the bar exam), and, if successful, may practice as a lawyer.

Comment: Look into Fernuni Hagen. It's a normal public university, but does mainly remote learning. Semester fees are average (~ EUR 600/year) but you will incur extra costs for examinations (e.g. travel to Germany or to a a Goethe Institute in your country). Courses are taught in German, so you will need to provide a certificate for C1 level language skill. Depending on where you live, attending a university in person might actually be cheaper. It goes without saying that a German uni teaches German law, so the degree might not be useful in other countries.

Comment: Useful information!

Answer (score 3):

- You can search for study programs via [Hochschulkompass](https://www.hochschulkompass.de/). There’s essentially just the [Bachelor of Laws](https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/studium/studienangebot/bachelor-of-laws.shtml) attainable at the *Fernuniversität in Hagen*. You can also do the [First Legal Examination](https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/studium/studienangebot/erstes-juristisches-staatsexamen.shtml) there, but
- if you really wanna become a *Volljurist*, i.e. a judge or an attorney, you will inevitably have to come to Germany, because the *Referendariat* can only be done here.
- Note, AFAIK it is not necessary to be an EU citizen to *study*, but you have to be a German to do any of the typical legal professions *here*, e.g. being appointed as a judge → [§ 9 no. 1 DRiG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_drig/englisch_drig.html#p0068). Naturalization is an entirely different issue, but I’ll rather mention that right away.

Comment: I highly doubt that you couldn’t practice as a lawyer at least if you reside in Germany as an EU citizen. There is typically no discrimination once someone becomes a resident in another member state. You can be a mayor of a town or probably a commissioner of a county or even a politician of a canton or state (you can’t be a national or federal representative though). Would be very surprising if you could t practice law. Taking a judgeship may be different.

Comment: German: [4 S. 1 no. 1 BRAO](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/brao/__4.html) → DRiG requirements;

Otherwise you’ll need to become a _European_ _Lawyer_ first, before becoming a “German” lawyer: That means you have to legally become a full lawyer in _your_ country of origin (EU+EEA+CH) _and_ work for three years on cases concerning European _and_ German law, either there or in Germany. Needless to say, but your country of origin, say France, will very likely have _similar_ _eligibility_ requirements and govern that you will need to have studied _French_ law at a university _in_ France.